# What is the meaning of "*=" operator in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, operators

I am kinda confused with Standard C Operators

in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html)  and [from here too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)

1)  int someInteger = 42;
      someInteger++;            // someInteger == 43

2)  int anotherInteger = 64;
      anotherInteger--;         // anotherInteger == 63

```
  anotherInteger *= 2;      // anotherInteger == 126
```

Looking at equation 2. with operators *=, if referring to hyperlink 2, it should be in this form a *= b , equals to a = a*b right?

on hyperlink 1, it should have 128 but (see equation 2, results in comments is 126)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `63*2=126`, what other value are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, `a *= b` is the same as `a = a * b` (except that `a` is evaluated only once). Also, I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: oh I see, I thought it was recalculated again based on anotherInteger= 64. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After line 2), anotherInteger is 63, so when dubling that in line 3), that will obviously be 126, not 128.

And yes, `a *= b` is the same as `a = a * b`.

Comment: thanks, I thought it was still calculated using anotherInteger = 64, so it was using 63. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct meaning. In line 2, after you assign anotherInteger = 64, you call anotherInteger--, subtracts 1, setting the value to 63 (as shown in your own comments.)